# Получить ID template Elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин

Мучаюсь третий день, решил спросить у знатоков. Внутри секции(template) Elementor использую виджет позволяющий работать с php и html кодом. Никак не могу вытянуть ID этой секции, применение стандартных функций WP (get_the_id(), $post->ID) получает ID страницы на которой находится секция, но не ID самой секции. Может кто-то решал подобную задачку? Вот пример кода:

```
`<div data-elementor-type="section" data-elementor-id="1012">
 <section class="container page-intro">
 <div class="header-text__links"><?php  the_breadcrumb() ?></div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h1><?php echo get_post_meta(1012,'title', true );?></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <p><?php echo get_post_meta(1012,'text', true );?></p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </section>      
  </div>`
```

Мне нужно получить ID секции, в данном случае это "1012" и использовать его в запросах к БД. Все, что мне удалось выловить в интернете это - "When you are in your own widget-class, which should extends Widget_Base, then you can use the get_id() Method like $this->get_id().
This method is in Control_stack class. Widget_Base extends Control_stack."

Comment: Попробуйте через `$template = get_page_template_slug($post->ID);`

Comment: спасибо, но это не поможет, мне не нужен индефикатор шаблона на котором построена страница, а нужен ID шаблона (секции) который вставлен в страницу при помощи Elementor. Наверное надо исправить вопрос, слово "шаблон" сбивает с толку)

Comment: Откуда получить при рендере самого виджета?

Comment: да, Вы абсолютно правы, при рендере самого виджета

Comment: $this->get_id() вернет вам id елемента, в данном случае вашего виджета, а не секции. Попробуйте $this->get_data('parent'). Или попробуйте через экш `elementor/frontend/section/before_render` и через него смотреть какие элементы в нем есть.

Comment: здесь замкнутый круг получается, я не могу использовать $this, у меня есть плагин который создал wp-widget <php\html> и я пользуюсь им чтобы вставить куски html верстки с php кодом в секцию елементора, и когда он парсит этот код у него понятия нету откуда здесь берется $this, он не видит классов елементора.